# Posting new-style status messages (with, picture and location)

Tags: facebook-graph-api, status

New-style status messages (as in mobile apps and web interface) have new properties e.g.

- **with** (people who are doing the activity with)
- **location** (your city or exact place)
- **picture** (to be posted to your Mobile Uploads or Wall Photos album and shown with the status message.

However in FB Graph object `Status`, sadly I can't find any of those features [developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/). What I want to do is post some status messages from my app and tag specific friends of user in the post (as "with" described above) and also post a picture with the status message.

How is that possible since `Status` object does not have an `attachment` field? Probably I need to use `object_tags` or `with_tags` (not documented in FB Graph API doc!) however could not adjust those parameters :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not yet possible to add this metadata to a stream Post or status message. With reference to object_tags and with_tags, it'd be great if you filed a bug report about that not being documented in the [FB Bug Tracker](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs)